# sql server +PHP select records which has non utf8 characters not working

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have an old application which uses `mssql_query()` for accessing database results from SQL SERVER.The issue I face now is for not utf8 usernames. For example ,username  is `usüß`.When I check in sql server its giving me the results.But in PHP page,it is giving me empty results.

```
SELECT userID  FROM user_table where username='usüß';
```

I know that mssql_query() is deprecated,but this is an old system. I have tried the following.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I have used

```
ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Nothing is working for me.Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried utf8 decode?

```php
$name = utf8_decode('usüß');
$sql = "SELECT userID  FROM user_table where username='$name'";
```

try this:

```php
$utf8 = 'usüß'; // file must be UTF-8 encoded
$iso88591_1 = utf8_decode($utf8);
var_dump($iso88591_1);

$iso88591 = 'usüß'; // file must be ISO-8859-1 encoded
$utf8_1 = utf8_encode($iso88591);
var_dump($utf8_1);
```

Comment: In my db, The records are in german letters.If I decode it, how can I decode the database results into utf8??

Comment: Sorry for the late response! to get the result from your db, just use `$utf8 = utf8_encode($result['name']);` or isn't this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SET NAMES?
It would be something like:

```
  <?php
        mssql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        //your query
  ?>
```